# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when retrieven data from WebApi to angular 2 application

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular

I am trying to retrieve data from a WebApi project I have created. I have build a new Angular 2 application, which going to get this data through an Api call.

Already have made the data ready in the WebApi project. If I use postman to call the Api, I get data like this example:

```
[
{
  "Id": 1,
  "BookingNr": "123456789",
  "OutboundDate": "2016-02-05T00:00:00",
  "ReturnDate": "2016-04-04T00:00:00",
  "Route": "Oslo - Stockholm",
  "Passengers": "1 Adult and 1 Child",
  "VehicleType": "Car 1.85m x 4.5m"
},
{
  "Id": 2,
  "BookingNr": "234567891",
  "OutboundDate": "2016-03-05T00:00:00",
  "ReturnDate": "2016-04-04T00:00:00",
  "Route": "Stockholm - Oslo",
  "Passengers": "2 Adult and 1 Child",
  "VehicleType": "Car 1.85m x 4.5m"
}
]
```

In my angular 2 project, I have a main component, which calls a service to get the data from the api.

**Main component:**

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'reservation-component',
    providers: [...FORM_PROVIDERS, BookingsService],
    directives: [...ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, BookingsListComponent ],
    styles: [`
        agent {
            display: block;
        }
    `],
    pipes: [],
    template: `
       ***No Html in this example***
  `,
  bindings: [BookingsService],
})

@Injectable()
export class BookingsComponent {

    bookings: Array<amendmentBookings> = [];

    constructor(public bookingsService: BookingsService) {

        this.bookings = this.bookingsService.getBookings();

    }

}
```

Then there is the Service, which makes the call.

**Service**

```
    @Injectable()
export class BookingsService {

    constructor(private router: Router, public http: Http) {
        console.log('Booking Service created.', http);
    }

    getBookings(): Array<amendmentBookings> {

        var bookingsRetrieved: Array<amendmentBookings>

        this.http.get('http://localhost:55350/api/bookings')
            .map(res => res.json())
            .map((bookings: Array<any>) => {
                let result: Array<amendmentBookings> = [];
                if (bookings) {
                    bookings.forEach(booking => {
                        result.push(
                            new amendmentBookings(
                                booking.bookingNumber,
                                new Date(booking.outboundDate),
                                new Date(booking.returnDate),
                                booking.route,
                                booking.passengers,
                                booking.vehicleType))
                    });
                }

                return result;

            }).subscribe(data => {
                bookingsRetrieved = data;
                console.log(bookingsRetrieved)
            },
            err => console.log(err));

        return bookingsRetrieved;
    }

}

export class amendmentBookings {

    constructor(
        public bookingNumber: string,
        public outboundDate: Date,
        public returnDate: Date,
        public route: string,
        public passengers: string,
        public vehicleType: string
    ) { }
}
```

When I try to call it, I get the following error:

[image]

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:55350/api/bookings. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.**

Have tried to search for the problem, but can only find that something is blocking the request, but no solution for it..

This is how my bookingsController looks like in Visual Studio (I'm using entity framework)

**BookingController**

```
public class BookingsController : ApiController
{
    private BookingsContext db = new BookingsContext();

    // GET: Bookings
    public IEnumerable<Booking> Get()
    {
        return db.Bookings.ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [`enable CORS`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) on your Web API if you want to be able to call it from javascript code hosted on a different domain.

So basically in your Web API bootstrap script you would call:

```
config.EnableCors();
```

and then decorate your controller with the proper attribute:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class BookingsController : ApiController
{
    ...
}
```

Of course enabling CORS for all domains (`*`) comes with its security implications so you might want to selectively enable it only for the domain on which your javascript calling code is hosted.

Comment: I give it a try.. 2min.

Comment: Thanks very much for your quick help. It worked, now I don't get any errors, only an object with invalid strings, but that's another case.